# How to lookup content of other sheet in formula?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have 2 sheets. One is titled `Equipment` and the other is `Technicians`.

What I would like to do is, on the `Technicians` sheet, in cell `F3`, I would like it to look on sheet `Equipment` from the range of `I2:I17` and look for `"Gene"`.

If `Gene` is found, then display the data from the corresponding cell in range `A2:A17`.

This should be displayed in cell `F3` on `Technicians` sheet.

Comment: You will need `INDEX/MATCH` to do this

Comment: Agreed with @cybernetic.nomad that this is a very straightforward `INDEX`/`MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` problem. There are numerous examples online (on this site and otherwise) where you can see how to accomplish this.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This site is a place where programmers share *specific* problems. Usually, questions include code (see **hot to create a [mcve]**) and an explanation of what's not working.  Check out the [tour] as well as "[ask]" and also the [help/on-topic] for more info.  There are several good tutorials online to help get you started.  Here's a [Microsoft Access Tutorial](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/) to get you started.

Comment: I have seen many examples of how to use these, but none that are specific about how I need to use them.

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit better to read. Please review my changes. In case you already have some code, please include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example you could do:

```
 =INDEX(Equipment!A2:A17, MATCH("gene",Equipment!I2:I17, 0), 1)
```

Once you get this working, it would be a good idea to understand how it's working so that you can apply this same logic again in the future to a slightly different range as this is powerful stuff that is very useful.